# react-native-keychain: AES storage throwing "could not encrypt data with alias: "

Tags: react-native, aes, react-native-keychain

I recently change the keychain storage to AES and now some users are experiencing the error `could not encrypt data with alias:`  after `Keychain.setGenericPassword(username, password)` is run.

I couldn't find from the documentation why I'd get such an error and I'm out of ideas of how to reproduce it.

Any idea of how to reproduce it or avoid it?

Comment: I'm getting this error on Android. No idea what's going on.

Comment: We are seeing this but possibly only on Android 5.0.1 on an old Samsung Galaxy S4. If we solve it I will get back to you.

Comment: FYI - I saw this error on a "Google Pixel 4a" running Android 12.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the report of the crash I am having:
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain/issues/567

I'll investigate more once I have a chance.